# How to pass parameters to a event handlerr in XML Views SAP UI5

Tags: parameter-passing, sapui5

I am having trouble sending data from the XML view to controller. It is easily achievable in JS views.

for example:-

In JS view:-

```
var btn = new sap.m.Button({
    text:"click",
    tap:function(){
          callFunction(oEvent, "mycustomString");
    }
});
```

How do I achieve the same using XML Views.

```
<Button text="click" tap="callFunction"/>
```

The above would only pass the event and not the "mycustomString".
How to I do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is an old question, but [as of version 1.56](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/53b4b5ec2c83408a8da2cb6b9154c246) there is now native support for passing parameters to handler functions directly in XML Views.

> **New Event Handler Parameter Syntax**
>
> When event handlers are assigned to control events in XML views, you can now also specify parameters which can be passed to the event handler. The parameters can be static values as well as bindings and even expressions. This feature helps to reduce controller code and avoid unnecessary controller methods, and separates the controller logic from the retrieval of the required input values.

So you can now simply do this:

```
<Button text="click" tap=".callFunction($event, 'mycustomString')" />
```

Note that as soon as you pass at least one parameter, the event itself will no longer be passed automatically, so you need to manually do so by passing `$event`, as I've done above. However, there is also additional syntax to pass event parameters, the source control, and data bindings directly, so you will likely not need the event at all.

The documentation for this feature is available online in the [Demo Kit](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/b0fb4de7364f4bcbb053a99aa645affe.html).

Short demo:

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function(Controller) {
  "use strict";

  return Controller.extend("myController", {
    callFunction: function(sButtonText, sVal) {
      alert("Clicked " + sButtonText + " with value " + sVal);
    }
  });
});

sap.ui.xmlview({
  viewContent: $('#myView').html()
}).placeAt('content');
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script id='sap-ui-bootstrap' src='https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js' data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m'></script>
    <script id="myView" type="sapui5/xmlview">
      <mvc:View controllerName="myController" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m">
        <Button text="Button 1" press=".callFunction(${$source>/text}, 'ABCDEF')" />
        <Button text="Button 2" press=".callFunction(${$source>/text}, 'UVWXYZ')" />
      </mvc:View>
    </script>
  </head>

  <body class='sapUiBody'><div id='content'></div></body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 23):

You can do this by adding a custom data-parameter `app:myData` in your view:

**View**

```
<mvc:View
    ...
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.sap.com/sapui5/extension/sap.ui.core.CustomData/1"
    ...
>
    <Button text="click" tap="callFunction" app:mydata="mycustomString"/>
    ...
```

**Controller**

```
callFunction: function(oControlEvent) {
    console.log("data: " + oControlEvent.getSource().data("mydata"));
}
```

logs `data: mycustomString`

See https://scn.sap.com/thread/3538029

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a function wrapper?

```
<Button text="click" tap="callFunctionWrapper"/>


callFunctionWrapper: function(oEvent) {
      callFunction(oEvent, "mycustomString");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by calling a function within the function you declare in **tap**.

**XML VIEW:**

```
<Button text="Press Me" tap="doSomething"/>
```

**Code in Controller.js:**

```
doSomething : function(oEvent) {
          yourNewFunction(oEvent, "String"); //maybe this callFunction(oEvent, "mycustomString");
}
```